# Gerar new Error e obter este erro no catch do controller

Tags: javascript, node.js

Em minha API feita em `Node`, eu faço a criação do usuário a partir de um service:

```
exports.create = async(data) => {
    try {

        let verifica = await UsuarioModel.findByUsername(data.username);

        if(verifica) throw new Error('Já existe um usuário cadastrado com este username');
        return 'verificado'; // o código é apenas um trecho

    } catch (error) {
        return error;
    }
}
```

No controller, eu apenas chamo este service da seguinte forma:

```
exports.create = async(req, res) => {
    try {
        let retorno = await UsuarioServices.create(req.body);

        console.log(retorno);


        res.status(201).send(retorno);
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).send(error);
    }
}
```

Entretanto, o erro gerado no service caso já exista um usuário com o mesmo username não é mostrado no retorno da requisição, apenas no `console.log()` é que eu consigo obter o erro gerado no service. Como faço para passar esse erro adiante e mostrar como um retorno da requisição?

Comment: Parece que você está usando exceções aonde não devia, dificilmente faz sentido capturar uma exceção que você mesmo cria, fora que um nome de usuário inválido não é algo excepcional, é algo normal, que, provavelmente, vai ocorrer com frequência

Answer (score 1):

Você está lançando um erro dentro de um bloco `try`. Seu erro é capturado pelo próprio bloco, e então retornado com um `return`. A esse ponto seu erro é apenas uma mensagem, não faz sentido retornar uma mensagem se você quer capturar o erro pela função que está invocando `UsuarioServices.create`.

```
exports.create = async(data) => {    
    if (await UsuarioModel.findByUsername(data.username))
        throw new Error('Já existe um usuário cadastrado com este username');

    return 'verificado'; // o código é apenas um trecho    
}
```

---

```
exports.create = async(req, res) => {
    try {
        let retorno = await UsuarioServices.create(req.body);
        console.log(retorno);    
        res.status(201).send(retorno);

    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).send(error.message);
    }
}
```